# Class inheritance python 3.6 : Similar methods

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, subclassing

I'm not the strongest pillar when it comes to class inheritance, so here goes my rather silly question. Following the code below, I would logically assume that after the 'super' call, the pointer arrives at self.example() which would in turn refer to the 'example' method in the same class and value 20 will be printed.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__():
        self.example()
    def example(self):
        print(20)

class B(A):
    def __init__():
       super().__init__()
    def example(self):
        print(10)

x = B()
```

Result : 10

This clearly isn't the case and 10 is printed instead. Could someone please shed some light on the mysterious world of class inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__():
        self.example()
    def example(self):
        print(20)

class B(A):
    def __init__():
       super().__init__()

x = B()
x.example()
```

Look for this, at example.

When you inherit B, from A, then method example is inheritated to B, you not must rewrite this to B. Of course still you can write this method for B, then you will override 'A' method, for objects of class B.

You also can use one class to Inheritance with many others:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Base created")

class ChildA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)

class ChildB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChildB, self).__init__()

ChildA()
ChildB()
```

ChildB have another call which is equivalent to that used in example above.

Comment: Actually, I just edited my code (my subclass B inherits from superclass A). So, if I understood well, when I instantiate class B, a call is made to the superclass A, which in turn calls the 'example' method. But since class B already has 'example' method, it overrides the 'example' method of class A and the value 10 is printed.

Comment: Yea, you understood it fine. But if B already has for example print(20). Then method `example` will be overrided and method will print 20 :). Even when `A` got that same method printing 10.